# Is it the correct way to create XML schema? Please suggest 

Tags: xsd

1:

```
  <xs:element name="abcd" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="4"/>
    </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

2:

```
<xs:element name="abcd" type="xs:string" length value = "4" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

Can I add `maxOccurs` and `minOccurs` as I have done in number 1. Is number 2 also correct way to define schema?

Comment: Next time please click the `{}` button to format your code lines. Otherwise XML code will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code example has a small syntax error. The `<xs:element>` start tag has a slash `/` in the end which makes it a self-closing element and your XML would be malformed. Removing the slash fixes that error.

```
<xs:element name="abcd" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <xs:simpl...
</xs:element>
```

Yes, you can generally add `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` as you have done, but this is not allowed for global element definitions (which means that `<xs:element>` is a (direct) child of the `<xs:schema>` element). The default values both for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` is 1, so in your example code the meaning would stay the same even if they were left out.

Your second example contains an error.

```
<xs:element name="abcd" type="xs:string" length value = "4" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

`length` is not a valid attribute for element `<xs:element>` Also the XML recommendation does not allow spaces before or after the equals character `=` but not all parsers complain about this. Otherwise it seems correct.